# Bound Index of Centralizer

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, sylow-theory

Let G be a finite group and P be a cyclic Sylow p-subgroup of order p and generator x, where p is the smallest prime that divides |G|. Show that $|N_G(P) : C_H(x)| < p$.

As a hint, I proved that $C_G(P) = C_H(P) = C_H(x)$, where $H = N_G(P)$. I am trying to bound the index via $P \le C_H(P) \le N_H(P) \le H \le G$ but can't figure out the proof. Any help?

Comment: There is a natural action of $N_G(P)$ on $P$, and $C_G(P)$ plays an important role in that action.

Comment: Is the action conjugation? Is there some result or theorem that links $C_G(P)$ with it?

Comment: Yes, the action is conjugation. What does conjugation with $y$ do on $P$ if $y \in C_G(P)$?

Comment: It sends each element back to itself under conjugation...is this the class equation?

Comment: Right, it does nothing. In other words, $C_G(P)$ is the kernel of the homomorphism $c \colon N_G(P) \to \operatorname{Aut}(P)$. Now, how large is $\operatorname{Aut}(P)$?

Comment: Is the argument that $|Aut(P)|$ is at most $(p-1)!$ and finish with the 1st Isomorphism Theorem?

Comment: It's actually exactly $p-1$, since an automorphism of $P$ is determined by the image of $x$. And I cannot remember the numbering of the isomorphism theorems, but it's $K/\ker f \cong \operatorname{im} f$.